# Looking for something similar to AdRotator in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, adrotator

I'm working on a website that has a rotation of testimonials. I need something that is similar to the `AdRotator` class in .NET. However instead of rotating images I'd like to rotate text blocks which are formated with HTML/CSS. The source can be an XML file just like the ad rotator but I need three elements.

```
Quote
Author Name
Author Position Title
```

Does anyone know of something in .NET that does this? If not then I guess I will start working on writing a thread safe solution.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Ok. So with no answers I'm assuming that I will be writing some custom code. Considering this will be a website is it best to write this as a static class that doesn't have to be instantiated on each page request? How does a static class stand up to being thread safe?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Google for JavaScript text rotators, you will find a lot of examples of what you want.  However, you will have to write the code to get the data from the XML file (or from a database) and write it out into the page in such a way that the JavaScript functions can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Closed. I've gone ahead and wrote my own utility method for this.